# X Axes time scale (hour format) in chart.js not working

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2, ng2-charts

Type time for unit hour not working in bar chart. 
            Expected behaviour: 
            Hours should be displayed in intervals.
            Result :
            By providing type - time and unit 'hour' graph is not loading
            Refer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc5hud32/) 
url [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pc5hud32/)
            Property used for displaying axesin the interval :
            [image: Snapshot] of the graph as in fiddle :

```
[![image ][1]][1]
Resource urls used
 [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/pc5hud32/
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoQ6s.jpg
```

Comment: For future travellers: Manhar got a response to a [github issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5603) (although no solution to the original issue is provided, it worked for me when using the config in the [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc5hud32/) using chart.js 2.7.2)